# Need help for navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, navigation-drawer

I have downloaded `ic_drawer.png` from https://developer.android.com/intl/es/samples/NavigationDrawer/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_drawer.html and paste it to `mipmap-hdpi`, `mipmap-mdpi`,`mipmap-xhdpi`,`mipmap-xxhdpi`. But I get cannot resolve symbol **ic_drawer**

```
  actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        );
```

How to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put the mipmap reference instead of drawable

```
R.mipmap.ic_drawer
```

as documented here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.mipmap.html